# Server at (localhost:27017) reports wire version (4), but this version of the Ruby driver requires at least (6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

Server at (localhost:27017) reports wire version (4), but this version of the Ruby driver requires at least (6).

i am using ubuntu 16.04
and ruby -v 3.0.2
rails 6.1.4.1

it not insert and fetch data from data base

Comment: I think the problem is that your database server uses wire version 4, but your database driver uses wire version 6, just as the error message says.

Comment: Try adding some screenshots and some specific question.

i.e. "How do I resolve the following error?...."

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. This error is raised by Mongo-Ruby-Driver from [line 71](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/master/lib/mongo/server/description/features.rb#L71).

The error states that Mongo-Ruby-Driver is not compatible with the MongoDB you are running.
I was running MongoDB with version 3.2, and updated it to  5.0.5, which works like a charm.

Here are the steps I took:

```
ps ax | grep mongo
```

Change processID with your Mongo process id:

```
kill -9 processID
```

Install latest Mongodb and unlink the old version:

```
brew install mongodb-community
brew unlink mongodb-community@3.2
```

Update LaunchAgent:

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

Update .zshrc if required:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Link & start MongoDB:

```
brew link mongodb-community
brew services restart mongodb-community
```

Start MongoDB:

```
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
# Make sure you have access rights to ~/data/db directory.
```

If you get this error:

```
Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
```

You can fix it by removing this file:

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```